# Objective c and SpriteKit - Set Player position

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I need to set the player position on the left of screen. If i use this
`player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/4, self.size.height/2);`, the player will be on the right. Instead with `CGPointMake(0,0)` the player is on the center of screen

```
_Player.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
_Player.name = @"Player";
[self addChild:player];
```

This game will be executed in portrait orientation.

Comment: What is self? Remember that 'position' of a node is always relative to the parent node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two principle you have to keep in mind :

1. The origin of sprite-kit coordinate system is on the lower left
   corner. In other word, node with default set (`node.anchor=(0,0)`, `node.position=(0,0)`) should always appear on lower left corner.
2. The `.Position` property of node is relative to its parent node

In your case, you have to check the frame of `_Player` parent node, then have a try to set the current position. more details could be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html)